# How to preserve the $_POST with my .htaccess rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

I have a this .htaccess rule for my lease form

```
RewriteRule ^(lease)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

which i am using with this PHP to file the proper file

```
$industries = array();
while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $industries[] = $row_r;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['route'])){
    $route = rtrim($_REQUEST['route'], '/');
    $home_page = ($route == '') ? true : false;
    $parts = explode('/', $route);
}else{
    $home_page = true;
}
if(!$home_page){
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/routes.php');
}
```

**routes.php file**

```
 $valid_pages = array('newsletter_subscribe', 'lease',....

$file = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
if (in_array($file, $valid_pages)) {
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/$file.php");
exit;
}else{
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/404.php");
exit;
```

this works great and i an getting to a pages/lease.php file. All is good but on the lease.php file i have a form that posts to itself like this

```
<?php  if((isset($_POST['submitform'])) && ($_POST['submitform'])) {
   echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST)."</pre>";
}

<form action="/pages/lease.php" method="post" id="app_form" name="app_form" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
<input type="text" name="print_config" value="email">
<p><input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Submit Application"></p>
....
```

BUT the POST is always empty...why is that and how do I preserve it..am I missing something

Comment: As long as your rewrite rule doesn't actually redirect the page (but just rewrites the path internally), your POST data is preserved because it's still using the same HTTP request. Also `pages/lease.php` doesn't match to the rule `^(lease)$` anyways...

Comment: sounds logical but the post is empty everytime....not sure it i am missing somethign

Comment: that did the trick....If you post an answer i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, ok:

As long as your rewrite rule doesn't actually redirect the page (but just rewrites the path internally), your POST data is preserved because it's still using the same HTTP request. Also `pages/lease.php` doesn't match to the rule `^(lease)$` anyways...

Although I don't really know which part answered your question. I'm assuming it was the form's action.

Comment: The part that answered my question was changing the form to  <form action="/lease rather then pages/lease.php did the trick ...thanks